# UITextField doesn't scale according to width specified

Tags: ios, swift

I want to programmatically create a UITextField and style it accordingly. 
I create my Field like

```
let userName = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 60, y: 60, width: 200.00, height: 200));
userName.placeholder = "Username";
userName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left;
userName.font = UIFont(name: "SpaceGrotesk-Light", size: 20.0);
userName.setBottomBorder()
view.addSubview(userName)
userName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
userName.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor,constant: 70).isActive = true;
userName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: WelcomeText.topAnchor,constant: 70).isActive = true;
```

This works but instead, the Field's width is same as the placeholder and does not increase but if you start typing in it then the field's width increases according to the text entered.
 I am a beginner and have no idea why this is happening. 
I tried to increase the width but no luck.

```
let userName = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 60, y: 60, width: 400.00, height: 200));
```

Comment: @Jbryson https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code

Comment: By uppercasing your variable userName, it is code highlighted as a class (like UITextField). This makes figuring out what is going on a bit more difficult. Hence the edit.

Comment: @Jbryson Okay I didn't know that so I rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's best to use lower-case for the start of variable names - so instead of

```
let UserName = UITextField(...)
```

use

```
let userName = UITextField(...)
```

But, that has nothing to do with the sizing.

You appear to be trying to "mix and match" explicit frames with auto-layout. Use one or the other.

Try it like this:

```
// we'll use constraints, so no need to set a frame
let UserName = UITextField();
UserName.placeholder = "Username";
UserName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left;
UserName.font = UIFont(name: "SpaceGrotesk-Light", size: 20.0);
UserName.setBottomBorder()
view.addSubview(UserName)

// this says "use auto-layout constraints"
UserName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

UserName.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor,constant: 70).isActive = true;
UserName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: WelcomeText.topAnchor,constant: 70).isActive = true;

// now, set your explicit width
UserName.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0).isActive = true
```

Or, if you want it to stretch based on the width of its superview:

```
// you have 70-pts padding from the left, so constrain to 70-pts padding from the right
// note that it should be negative (because you want it *from* the right-edge)
UserName.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -70).isActive = true
```

Comment: _it's best to use lower-case for the start of variable names_ why?

Comment: Also, can you tell me about how frames are different

Comment: It's widely used convention, to help keep things orderly... Upper-case for Class names, e.g. `UITextField`, and lower-case for variables, e.g. `myTextField`.

Comment: Okay will follow that convention but it is allowed, right?

Comment: You *can* use frames with auto-layout, by setting the `.autoresizingMask` property. However, constraints can do much more, and make it much easier to design for adaptive layouts (different screen sizes and orientations).  See: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html

Comment: You can use whatever case you want -- `let UsErnaME = UITextField();` -- is perfectly "legal." But when you give your code to someone else to work on, or when you get someone else's code, using "standard conventions" makes things easier.

Comment: that docs you linked are no longer updated. Should i still refer to them?

Comment: It's still valid. There is a ton of information about auto-layout in Apple's docs, as well as all over the web. But that's a reasonable starting point.

Comment: @window.document And don't use semicolons

Comment: @RajeshKumarR I apologize for my lack of knowledge of coding conventions for swift. Thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [updateConstraints](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622512-updateconstraints) or [layoutIfNeeded](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622507-layoutifneeded) function after created the view and configure your constraint

```
userName.updateConstraints()
or
userName.layoutIfNeeded()
```